# Get number of filtered docs from Lucene search

Tags: java, lucene

I am doing a Lucene search with a bunch of filters like this:

```
searcher.search(query, getFilters(), collector);
```

I would like to find out how many documents matched the query but were filtered out. Is that possible already or do I need to subclass some Lucene class and if so, which one and how?